# Align text and image side by side

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to wrap my head around this simple problem. I am trying to position text next an image

My HTML:

```
<article>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150" />
    <h3>Long title should go right here</h3>
</article>
```

My CSS:

```
img {
    display: inline-block;
}

h3 {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

This works, but as soon as the title breaks and moves to the next line, the entire h3 tags moves to the bottom of the page. I have a feeling this is not the right way to approach this. Hopefully I can get some answers.

Comment: Seems OK here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LG9Vm/

Comment: Do you want the title to go above the image when the window shrinks? Do you want the text to the right of the window? Do you want it justified to the top of the image or the bottom?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LG9Vm/3/)

**CSS**

```
img {
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
}

h3 {
   line-height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use float instead:

```
img {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot. Just had to add a width and height to my image and it works perfectly. Thanks.